# How to switch back to mobile version after switching to desktop version?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, mobile-web

On my mobile device (iphone safari), after I switched to full site view, I wasn't able to find the link to switch back to mobile view.

How to go back to mobile view without clear cookies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Comment: Now that's a fat FHRC.